# When do we need to use posix_memalign instead of malloc?

Tags: c, alignment

Seems `posix_memalign` let you choose a customized `alignment`,but when is that necessary?

`malloc` has already done the alignment work internally.

**UPDATE**

The exact reason I ask this is because I see nginx does this,`ngx_memalign(NGX_POOL_ALIGNMENT, size, log);`,here `NGX_POOL_ALIGNMENT` is defined as `16`, [nginxs.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/src/core/ngx_palloc.c](http://nginxs.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/src/core/ngx_palloc.c)

Comment: We' d better read the offical doc as follows :  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html

Answer (score 16):

Basically, if you need tougher alignment than malloc will give you. Malloc generally returns a pointer aligned such, that it may be used with any of the primitive types (often, 8 bytes on common desktop machines).

However, sometimes you need memory aligned on other boundaries, for example 4K-aligned, etc. In this case, you would need `memalign`.

You would need this, for example,

- when writing a memory manager (such as a garbage collector). In this case, it is sometimes handy to work with memory aligned on larger block sizes. This way, you can store meta-data common to all objects in a given block at the bottom of the allocated area, and access this simply by masking the least significant bits of the object pointer.
- when interfacing with hardware (never done this myself, but IIRC, certain kinds of block-devices require aligned memory). See n.m.'s answer for details.

Comment: @Dirk,seems this doesn't answer **when** we need.

Comment: More examples: SIMD types might need more alignment than `malloc` provides. Code playing very fancy tricks for performance might want alignment that corresponds to the cache line size - this is perhaps most common if you're writing a dynamic linker (i.e. code to load executables into memory), the code that you're loading might want its functions aligned on cache line boundaries.

Comment: @Steve Jessop,will we benifit if the memory size of `16*1024` and aligned by `16` instead of the default `8`?

Comment: @Steve: §7.20.3 "The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to **any type of object** and then used to access such an object..." (emphasis added).  In practice, this means that on modern 64-bit systems with 128-bit SIMD units, `malloc` returns memory aligned to 16 byte boundaries even though pointers are only 8 (or 4) bytes wide.

Comment: @Dietrich: that might be what it means, but it's not what implementations actually do. You can live with this, or you can declare both MSVC and GCC non-conforming and refuse to write for them. In which case you probably need a different line of work than C programming ;-) As far as I'm aware, the get-out reasoning is that since SIMD types are extensions to the standard, the implementation is allowed to "break" code that uses them by introducing this additional requirement that memory be super-aligned.

Comment: Huh, I thought glibc-malloc always returned 16-byte aligned pointers on x64... and on OS X, malloc is also 16-byte aligned (on PPC and x86).  Are there architectures where this is not true?  (MSVC and GCC don't have malloc implementations, they're just compilers)

Comment: @Dietrich: well, I'm on a 32 bit Intel chip, and cygwin malloc is returning merely 8-aligned pointers. As far as I know, my 128bit SSE instructions require 16-alignment. It may just be that cygwin is too weird for glibc to cope with, or the distributors mis-configured it, but I thought this was typical. I remember reading a glibc bug report some time ago that got fairly heated, in which some gcc people and some glibc people both argued that if it needed doing at all, it certainly wasn't them that was going to do it. So I assumed it didn't get done, maybe by now it is on some platforms.

Comment: @Dietrich - and you're right, GCC doesn't have a `malloc` implementation, but it also doesn't *have* to call glibc malloc just because the programmer puts a call to `malloc` in his code. In particular, if the system `malloc` *were* in some way insufficiently aligned for the types that the compiler offered, then the compiler *would* have to wrap system `malloc` in its own implementation of standard `malloc` in order to provide a conforming implementation. Thank goodness there is not usually any such falling-out between compiler and library writers.

Answer (score 9):

The only benefits of `posix_memalign`, as far as I can tell, are:

1. Allocating page-aligned (typically 4096 or larger alignment) memory for hardware-specific purposes.
2. Evil hacks where you keep the low `N` bits of a pointer zero so you can store an `N`-bit integer in the low bits. :-)

Comment: @compile-fan, if the objects you're pointing to are all larger than, say, 4-bytes, and aligned on 4-byte boundaries, you can steal 2 bits from the bottom of the pointer if you always mask them to zero before using the pointer as a pointer.

Comment: the exact reason I ask this is because I see nginx does this,`ngx_memalign(NGX_POOL_ALIGNMENT, size, log);`,here `NGX_POOL_ALIGNMENT` is defined as `16`,http://nginxs.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/src/core/ngx_palloc.c

Comment: It sounds like nginx is managing its own memory pools, basically replicating `malloc` on top of its own allocated block(s), and wants to be sure it can provide alignment up to 16 bytes. I'm not sure why it cares about this since `malloc` will already provide alignment sufficient for any C types, and if you used a block obtained by `malloc` and didn't apply un-aligned offsets when slicing it up, it would remain aligned. Judging from the past series of questions about nginx, I question whether the authors of nginx understood why they were using `memalign` in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

Various hardware may have alignment requirements which `malloc` cannot satisfy. The Linux man page gives one such example, I quote:

> On many systems there are alignment
>   restrictions, e.g. on buffers used for
>   direct block device I/O. POSIX
>   specifies the
>   pathconf(path,_PC_REC_XFER_ALIGN) call
>   that tells what alignment is needed.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of uses:

- Some processors have instructions that will only work on data that is aligned on a power of two greater than or equal to the buffer size - for example bit reverse addressing instructions used in ffts (fast fourier transforms).
- To align data to cache boundaries to optimize access in multiprocessing applications so that data in the same cache line isn't being accessed by two processors simultaneously.

Basically, if you don't need to do absurd levels of optimizations and/or your hardware doesn't demand that an array be on a particular boundary then you can forget about posix_memalign.

Comment: what do you mean by `cache boundaries` and `cache line`?