# When is posix_memalign/memalign used?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, posix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do we need to use posix_memalign instead of malloc ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410609/when-do-we-need-to-use-posix-memalign-instead-of-malloc)

When would you need "`size` bytes of memory such that the allocation's base address is an exact multiple of `alignment`" over just a simple `malloc()`?

---

I believe it is `memalign()` under Linux and `posix_memalign()` under Mac OS X/BSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common use cases is when working with SIMD code (SSE, AltiVec, AVX, Neon, etc) where you typically need all buffers to be aligned on a SIMD vector boundary (16 byte or 32 byte alignment).

Another common alignment requirement is virtual memory page alignment (4 kB typically).

Answer (score 2):

One reason that popped up recently is to ensure that data buffer structs/objects do not share cache lines.  This reduces the need for cache flushes.

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

if you need strict memory alignment than what `malloc` offers.

`malloc` usually would return a pointer aligned in such away that it may be used with any of the primitive types (usually 8 bytes).

However, sometimes you need memory aligned on other boundaries, In this case, you would need `memalign`.

Answer (score 0):

Some special instructions (eg. SSE instructions) require correct alignment of data in order to work. If you're developing in kernel mode, some DMA controllers also require correct alignment.