# What is the diffrence btw memalign() and malloc()

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Came across a code which allocate memory like this:

```
int iPage_size = getpagesize ();
int iNeedSize = (iNeedSize + iPage_size - 1) & ~(iPage_size - 1);
void* iBuffer = memalign (iPage_size, iNeedSize);
```

**1. So why is that different from this:**

```
void* iBuffer = malloc(iNeedSize);
```

**2. And can I re-allocate that buffer** which is allocated by `memalign` using `realloc`? or do I need to `free` it first and do `memalign` again?

Thanks.

P/s: above snippets of code is taken from a code working on V4L2-driver device.

Comment: See previously answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410609/when-do-we-need-to-use-posix-memalign-instead-of-malloc

Comment: yes, it answered half of my question. How about the number 2?

Comment: See previously answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078259/realloc-alignment

Comment: yep, you re right

Comment: dont change your question after beeing posted. Unless you improve the wording or such but you deleted some crucial parts, please revert it.